# How do I complete a Standard Visitor visa application form for children under 10 years?

Tags: paperwork, children, standard-visitor-visas

I am from India and I am planning to travel to UK on a tourist visa with my wife and two children of age 7 years and 1 year. I have filled the application form for myself and my wife. My wife and I are both working and have our own individual incomes that we have mentioned in our respective application forms. However, while filling out the separate Standard Visitor visa application form for my 7 year and 1 year old child, I have come across the same set of questions that I had answered for myself:

Can I mention "Not Applicable" to these questions below as they are dependent on us for all the trip related expenses?

*What is your employment status?*  "Not Applicable"

*How much money are you planning to spend on your visit to UK?* "Not Applicable"

*What is the total amount of money you spend each month?*  "Not applicable"

*Will anyone be paying towards the cost of your visit?*  - "Yes"

*Who will be paying towards the cost of your visit?* - My Name and address.

*Why they are helping to pay for your visit?* "They are my parents and they are my caretakers for everything". So, that's why they are paying for my visit."

*Give details of your visit, including things you plan to do and places you will go, plus any other activities such as a school exchange?*  - May be the same answer that I filled for my application.

Are these answers okay to fill in the application form for my child who is just 7 years and 1 year old?

Comment: No. I will submit all the applications together once I am done with all the 4 applications.

Answer (score 3):

You are completing a family application that includes children and have some generic questions.

> Should I put "Not applicable" for text fields that are clearly meant
>   for adults? (e.g., *What is your employment status?*)

For children, you can answer "not applicable" or for figures put "0".  What is fundamentally important is to fill out the part about "*Are you travelling with anyone*".

It is also "best practices' to put your (and your wife's) GWF number in the child's remarks section. I cannot stress this point enough. It allows the assistants to 'group' the applications in [Proviso](http://icinspector.independent.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/An-inspection-of-the-UK-Border-Agency-Visa-Section-in-New-York.pdf) (their system).

---

In comments you raised the *related* question that can be treated as a part of this answer...

> Also there is a question later where the following questions are
>   asked:
>
> - **"Who is paying towards the cost of your visit?"
> - "How much money will they be paying towards your visit?"**
>
> So, should what should we fill for these questions? If we don't
>   answer, the form does not proceed. We cannot answer "0" or "Not
>   applicable" either

For the children, you would enter the primary's name (i.e., the father's name) **and his GWF number**.  For the amount you would provide a proportional estimate, like 1/5th of the total amount. *They are not idiots* and would understand that for children the amounts are pro-forma estimates. It is the answers in the primary's application that are paramount.

> But the application does not proceed unless I mention some value
>   greater than 0 to all questions.

The form is buggy for situations like that (i.e., the applications are linked), this is known and the programme is still evolving from 'beta' status.  There are on-going changes to the underlying programme taking place at regular intervals. And in the background [people](http://ilpa.org.uk) are meeting with the [Chief](http://icinspector.independent.gov.uk/) and making representations.  They are also making representations to the [Home Affairs Committee](http://www.parliament.uk/business/committees/committees-a-z/commons-select/home-affairs-committee/) when called upon to do so.

If you reach a state where the programme has created an illogical condition and will not advance to the next section, enter a pro-forma number and make a note of it in the remarks section.  Once again, *they are not idiots and will not refuse an application* where the programme created an illogical state.

You should also make a note on the 'feedback' page they will send to you. This step is very important.

---

**Other notes**

- The other thing to remember is the children should not submit copies
  of your evidence. Only the primary should submit bank statements etc.
- As both parents are travelling there's no [Hague issues](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/international-parental-child-abduction) or
  [Childrens Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1989/41/contents) entanglements, but be sure to include birth
  certificates naming the bio parents.
- It is also 'best practices' to show how and where the children will
  be cared for during their visit.

Comment: Thank you. However, When I tried, the system does not allow "Not applicable" or "0" to be as answers for the questions involving figures. In that case, what is the figure that I should provide?

Comment: Also, "How much money do you plan to spend on your trip"? For this question, should I break up the total amount into each of the 4 applications?

Comment: No, there is a primary who completes those sections.

Comment: But the application does not proceed unless I mention some value greater than 0 to all questions. Also there is a question later where the following questions are asked: "Who is paying towards the cost of your visit?"  "How much money will they be paying towards your visit?" So, should what should we fill for these questions? If we don't answer, the form does not proceed. We cannot answer "0" or "Not applicable" either.

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal I added your comment to the body of the answer because the point you raise is inexorably related to your original question. Please read the answer in its entirety again, thanks.